# Auditd stops monitoring USB mount point when USB is removed then reinserted

Tags: usb, audit

I'm working on scripted monitoring of USB activity: file reads, writes, folder creations, etc. Our codebase automatically sets up a mount point in: `/media/usb/mounted_usb_name`, when a USB device is inserted, and deletes this mount point when the USB is removed.

I've configured `auditd` to watch `/media/usb` using the following rules:

```
-w /media/usb -p r -k USB_r
-w /media/usb -p w -k USB_w
-w /media/usb -p a -k USB_a
-w /media/usb -p x -k USB_x
```

... to be able to identify distinct types of activity in the `auditd` log.

This works fine for the most part; I'm able to see log activity for all kinds of operations in the mounted USB location. However, when I remove and re-plug the USB, causing the mount directory to be deleted and recreated via our codebase, `auditd` stops reporting any and all activity to the log.

There's no difference in owners or permissions between the two created mount points. I've also tried creating folders directly in `/media/usb`, deleting them, and recreating them, and `auditd` has no issue tracking these folders whenever present. I've checked syslog, but the only lead I've found there is the line:

```
Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupted. Please run fsck.
```

... which occurs when the USB is *plugged in*, rather than removed.

I've tried with multiple USBs and on two different machines. Behaviour is consistent. The only thing that seems to fix the issue is running:

```shell
systemctl restart auditd
```

... which isn't a good option for our goals.

I'd appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

auditd 'watches' tracks files by their inode, if you delete the directory on which 'watch' was and recreate it, the inode is changed and 'watch' stops tracking the file in question.

try using `-F path=` to track file by it's absolute path

`auditctl -a always,exit -F path=/media/usb`